# Python controlling the output "print"

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, output

```
all_path = [[[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]],
            [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]], 
            [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]], 
            [[4, 5]],
            [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5]]]
s_dict = {1: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0000.00', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '00.00'}, 
          2: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0000.00', 'Stops': '11', 'Time': '00.00'}, 
          3: {'Origin': '002', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1450.11', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '00.00'}, 
          4: {'Origin': '004', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '1550.11', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '22.22'}, 
          5: {'Origin': '001', 'Destination': '005', 'Cost': '0000.00', 'Stops': '99', 'Time': '11.00'}}


for tin in range(1,6):
   print  'From: '+str(int(s_dict[tin]['Origin']))+','+' to: '+str(int((s_dict[tin]['Destination'])))+','+' Stops: '+(s_dict[tin]['Stops'])+','+' Cost: '+(s_dict[tin]['Cost'])+','+' Time: '+(s_dict[tin]['Time']) 
   print  'All routes:'
   for n in range(len(all_path[tin-1])):
       l=''
       for s in range(len(all_path[tin-1][n])):
           l+=   str(all_path[tin-1][n][s])+'->'
       print l
```

and this is the output,
I will quote one part

> From: 2, to: 5, Stops: 99, Cost: 0000.00, Time: 00.00
>
> All routes:
>
> 2->3->4->5->
>
> 2->4->5->
>
> 2->5->

my problem is that extra ' -> '
at the end of the line
I want it to be something more like

> 2->3->4->5

is there a way to not show "an extra" ' -> ' at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)-method:

```
print '->'.join(str(x) for x in all_path[tin-1][n])
# print '->'.join(map(str, all_path[tin-1][n]))

> print '->'.join(['1', '2', '3'])  # '->'.join('123')
1->2->3
```